# Load .csv file from current directory with Bulk Insert: SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am currently trying to do a bulk insert in a `.sql` file to insert `.csv` data into one of my SQL Server database's table. However, I need to be able to load the `.csv` file from its relative directory instead of using the full path. The `.csv` file is currently in the same directory as the `.sql` file.

I would like to do something like this

```
BULK INSERT team
FROM './FinalProject/teams.csv'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV', 
    FIELDQUOTE = '"',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
);
GO
```

but it cannot find the file.

How can I load the file without hardcoding its path?

Comment: That's very product specific. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS currently.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a dynamic path, then you need a dynamic query. Build your `BULK IMPORT` statement before you execute it, as it does not accept a dynamic path.

```sql
/* figure out your dynamic path before this point, and store it here */
DECLARE @mypath varchar(50) = './FinalProject/teams.csv' 

/* build your BULK INSERT query */
DECLARE @sql varchar(max) = 'BULK INSERT team 
FROM '''+@mypath+'''
WITH
(
    FORMAT = ''CSV'', 
    FIELDQUOTE = ''"'',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
);'

PRINT @sql -- debug

/* run your BULK INSERT query */
EXEC(@sql)
```